# How to remove a path from list of path in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I would like to add a checking to remove ../../../source_code/google_test/mock/mock_StateMachine.cpp if i run my testfile which name is ../../../source_code/google_test/test/test_StateMachine.cpp.

```
    ../../../source_code/google_test/test/test_StateMachine.cpp
    ../../../source_code/google_test/test/main_testall.cpp
    ../../../source_code/basesw/20_foundation/sm/StateMachine.cpp
    ../../../source_code/google_test/mock/mock_ModuleProp.cpp
    ../../../source_code/google_test/mock/mock_SuspendState.cpp
    ../../../source_code/google_test/mock/mock_HWConnFilter.cpp
    ../../../source_code/google_test/mock/mock_EvApplState.cpp
    ../../../source_code/google_test/mock/mock_Mutex.cpp
    ../../../source_code/google_test/mock/mock_StartState.cpp
    ../../../source_code/google_test/mock/mock_IApplication.cpp
    ../../../source_code/google_test/mock/mock_ApplicationStateBase.cpp
    ../../../source_code/google_test/mock/mock_StateMachine.cpp
```

Here is source code that add the mock_Filename.cpp if any testfile match the pattern test_Filename.cpp. How to modify it to remove the mock_Filename.cpp if any testfile match the pattern test_Filename.cpp ?

```
srcs_gtest = srcs_gtest + [source_file for source_file in srcs_mock_gtest \
            if any(fnmatch(test_file, "*" + "test" + (os.path.basename(source_file)[4:])) for test_file in srcs_gtest)]
```

So that my expected result is :

```
../../../source_code/google_test/test/test_StateMachine.cpp
../../../source_code/google_test/test/main_testall.cpp
../../../source_code/basesw/20_foundation/sm/StateMachine.cpp
../../../source_code/google_test/mock/mock_ModuleProp.cpp
../../../source_code/google_test/mock/mock_SuspendState.cpp
../../../source_code/google_test/mock/mock_HWConnFilter.cpp
../../../source_code/google_test/mock/mock_EvApplState.cpp
../../../source_code/google_test/mock/mock_Mutex.cpp
../../../source_code/google_test/mock/mock_StartState.cpp
../../../source_code/google_test/mock/mock_IApplication.cpp
../../../source_code/google_test/mock/mock_ApplicationStateBase.cpp
```

Comment: Can you please explain - is your code supposed to delete any `mock_FileName.cpp` for `test_FileName.cpp`, or for `test_StateMachine.cpp` only?

Comment: HI, @AlexanderPushkarev, updated my question. Myr code supposed to delete any mock_FileName.cpp for test_FileName.cpp matched.

Answer (score 0):

It is not well-thought approach, but you can probably

1. Find out if your file fits the pattern

```py
>>> import re
>>> s = '../../../source_code/google_test/test/test_StateMachine.cpp'
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> match = re.search(r"test_[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.cpp", s)
>>> match.start(0)
38
>>> s[38:]
'test_StateMachine.cpp'
>>>
```

2. Then form a filename for files that should be filtered

```py
>>> filename_to_filter = 'mock_' + s[38 + len('test_'):]
>>> filename_to_filter
'mock_StateMachine.cpp'
```

3. and finally filter you list:

```py
>>> files_list = []
>>> files_list.append('../../../source_code/google_test/test/test_StateMachine.cpp')
>>> files_list.append('../../../source_code/google_test/test/mock_StateMachine.cpp')
>>> files_list.append('../../../source_code/google_test/test/mock_StateMachine1.cpp')
>>> files_list.append('../../../source_code/google_test/test/mock_StateMachine2.cpp')
>>> file_lists_to_filter = []
>>> for l in files_list:
...   m = re.search(r"test_[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.cpp", l)
...   if m:
...    filename_to_filter = 'mock_' + s[m.start(0) + len('test_'):]
...    file_lists_to_filter.append(filename_to_filter)
...

>>> files_list = [x for x in files_list if not x.endswith(filename_to_filter)]
>>> files_list
['../../../source_code/google_test/test/test_StateMachine.cpp', '../../../source_code/google_test/test/mock_StateMachine1.cpp', '../../../source_code/google_test/test/mock_StateMachine2.cpp']
```

(last part certainly can be optimized)

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer:

## exclude mock_Filename.cpp if test_Filename.cpp is exist:

```
for test_file in srcs_gtest:
      if fnmatch(test_file, "*" + "test" + (os.path.basename(source_file)[4:])):
           srcs_gtest.remove(test_file)
```